# Make the type checker accept polymorphic recursive interface implementation

Tags: idris

I'm trying to figure out why the type-checker rejects this:

```
module Test

import Data.Vect
import Data.HVect

data Tree = Leaf | Branch (Vect n Tree)

data Garble : Tree -> Type where
  Farble : Garble Leaf
  Marble : HVect (map Garble children) -> Garble (Branch children)

Eq (Garble tree) where
  Farble == Farble = True
  (Marble comps1) == (Marble comps2) = comps1 == comps2 -- breaks here
  _ == _ = False
```

This complains because it can't find an instance for `Eq (HVect (map Garble children))` in the `Marble` case of the `Eq` instance. I suspect that's because the `map` expression isn't reduced prior to interface resolution, or that polymorphic recursion is somehow responsible for this, e.g. that there's no instance available for `Eq (Garble tree')` where `tree' /= tree`...

Well, enlighten me :)